# Excluir todas as referências que não estão em uso no Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, organização-de-projeto

Desejo excluir todas as referências (não estou falando dos `using` nos arquivos de classes) que não estão sendo utilizadas. Para isso, claro, preciso pelo menos de uma forma eficaz de descobrir quais as referências não estão em uso.

Entendam "referências" como as referências do Projeto.

Vide print:

[image: Solution Explorer]

Existe uma forma simples e automática de realizar esta tarefa?

Answer (score 3):

Para C# o Visual Studio não faz isto. Precisa de alguma extensão. O [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) faz e é uma ótima opção. Mas se só quiser esta funcionalidade e não quiser gastar há uma [extensão](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=battas.ResolveUR-ResolveUnusedReferences).

Comment: Poderia explicar como identificar essas referências com o Resharper?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Remove_Unused_References.html

Answer (score 1):

O [ResolveUR](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=battas.ResolveUR-ResolveUnusedReferences) resolve seu problema se você não optar por usar o Resharper.